# Neither 'BinaryExpression' object nor 'Comparator' object has an attribute 'filter'

Tags: postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

I try to overlap dates using 'and_()' but I've got error: Neither 'BinaryExpression' object nor 'Comparator' object has an attribute 'filter'

```
dto = date(year=2021, month=4, day=15)
dfrom = date(year=2021, month=4, day=27)
schema = BookSchema(many=True)
bookings = db.session.query(BookData).filter(and_(func.date(BookData.date_from).between(dfrom, dto)).filter(and_(func.date(BookData.date_to).between(dfrom, dto)))).all()
```

Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Please read documentation on how to use [`and_`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.and_) correctly.

Your query should looks like this:

```
bookings = (
    db.session
    .query(BookData)
    .filter(
        and_(
            func.date(BookData.date_from).between(dfrom, dto),
            func.date(BookData.date_to).between(dfrom, dto),
        )
    )
    .all()
)
```

In fact, given that the filter can be applied to the query construction multiple times and doing so implies `AND` anyways, the below will be exactly the same:

```
bookings = (
    db.session
    .query(BookData)
    .filter(func.date(BookData.date_from).between(dfrom, dto))
    .filter(func.date(BookData.date_to).between(dfrom, dto))
    .all()
)
```